# tanh function values are either 1 or -1, how to interpret that distribution

Tags: activation-function

I have a question regarding the tanh function. I trained an NN (with tanh activation functions in hidden layers) on a multiclass dataset and visualised the tanh values of the complete samples from the dataset passed through the NN.

The question is why I only have the -1 and 1 values? What does it mean can we conclude something from that?

[image]

thank a lot

Comment: almost nothing can be concluded. It may be the result of bad architecture, type of data or simply be normal

Comment: The use of activation function is used to make linear data as non-linear.  Just like sigmoid returns you the values as either 0 or 1, tanh also generates values  either -1 or +1 .

Comment: tanh can also produce values between -1 and +1 @SaandeepSreerambatla